# How to find relationship between switching energy loss, temperature and current in an IGBT

Tags: diodes, power-electronics, igbt

I am calculating the losses of an inverter in Simulink. I used 'IGW25N120H3' IGBT for the inverter.

In the [datasheet](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/DS_IG25N120H3_1_1_final.pdf?folderId=db3a30431c69a49d011c6f86019b00a1&fileId=db3a304325305e6d01258d0f50a8369e), they have mentioned switching energy losses for 2 different temperatures and from other graphs in datasheet, I got the information on collector current.

But now I need to find the relationship between switching energy loss, temperature and collector current, as my loss calculations are dependent on current and temperature.

How can I estimate the switching loss in an IGBT?

Comment: Last time I did something similar, I made a linear model for the temperature dependence. Pretty much whatever you simulate in terms of losses will not be very accurate in the end, at least not to the degree where the tempeture dependence will matter.

Answer (score 1):

I usually use spice to estimate switching losses, the first thing I do is make sure the FET model is right, then I calculate the energy from the device and filter it, then use a time constant witch is close to that of the package of the device. The picture below shows a spice energy calculation with an RC time constant:

[image]

Another thing that would be useful would be to integrate this with the FET package thermal junction conductivity, but I haven't done that yet, I'm mostly interested in the average ammount of power from a device or FET.